# How to parse Twitter Search JSON response in C#?

Tags: c#, json, twitter

I receive the JSON response from Twitter Search but how can I loop through them?

```
 protected void BtnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?&q=felipe&rpp=40");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);// fill the buffer with data

            if (count != 0)// make sure we read some data
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);// translate from bytes to ASCII text

                sb.Append(tempString);// continue building the string
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); //I can see my JSON response here
        //object deserializeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sb.ToString());


    }
```

Comment: Have you seen the TweetSharp (https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) library? It'll handle the heavy lifting and will give you strongly typed classes so that you don't need to do parsing yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would make use of `dynamic` keyword

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{

    var json = wc.DownloadString("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?&q=felipe&rpp=40");
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    foreach (var result in obj.results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}:\n{2}\n\n", result.from_user_name, 
                                                 (DateTime)result.created_at, 
                                                 result.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error message when I use your code. 
_'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'results'_

Comment: @wallace740 I just tested it and worked correctly. Debug your code and see what you get in `json`

Comment: I created a new page and tested your code, it works indeed. Thx a lot @L.B  
This whole Json stuff was completely new for me, I'm still struggling with it

Comment: 1 up for the excellent answer. In twitter 1.1, we need to look at the statuses rather than 'results' .i.e. use foreach (var result in obj.statuses). The fields to output can be worked out by debugging.

Answer (score 1):

A strongly typed way..

```
public class MyTwitterClass
{

    public List<CustomObject> data {get; set;}
}

public class CustomObject 
{

    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
string someJson=
    @"{""data"":[{""id"":""1"",""name"":""name1""}, {""id"":""2"",""name"":""name2""}]}";

MyTwitterClass someTwitterData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyTwitterClass>(someJson);

foreach(var item in someTwitterData.data)
{
  Console.Write(item.id + " " + item.name);
}
```

Having said all that you may want to check this out

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The below example should help you, where "result" is the returned JSON

```
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

        foreach (JObject item in stuff)
        {
            foreach (JProperty trend in item["user"])
            {
                if (trend.Name == "name")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(trend.Value.ToString());

                }
                else if (trend.Name == "followers_count")
                {
                    // GET COUNT
                }
                else if (trend.Name == "profile_image_url")
                {
                    // GET PROFILE URL
                }
            }
        }
```